# Android app finding path to SD card

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set a file location in the graphhopper demo app. Because it needs large files, I want to save those to the SD Card. So far it always saves the files to the internal storage. Here is the code I use;

`mapsFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/mnt/sdcard/download/graphhopper/maps/");`

I have tried changing "/mnt/sdcard/download/graphhopper/maps/" to other names and directories but this just changes the name of the folder that it creates in the internal storage.

I guess what I'm asking is for some help trying to find the path to the SD Card.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Thank you in advance`. Bad idea. Moreover i see no questions.

Comment: `Android app won't save data to SD card`. Wrong. You do not even know the path of the sd card.